# Ember.js - How to trigger view method from controller?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to call view method from controller, but no idea how to do this. From view I can easily call controller method like `this.get('controller').send('method');`

**How to do something like that from controller `this.get('view').send('method');`?**

*To give you better overview what I'm trying to do.*

I have application controller `Ember.Controller.extend({})` I have application view `Ember.View.extend({})` and application template.

In application template is login form, when user submit it controller method is executed. In this method if login credentials are incorrect I need to call view method which is executing `jQueryUI` method on login form (shake method to be exact and showing some text).

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This sounds like a good use for `Ember.Evented`. By using event subscription and dispatching you can avoid coupling your view and controller.

Simply mixin `Ember.Evented`:

```
Controller = Ember.Controller.extend(Ember.Evented)
```

Now you can call `on` and `trigger` methods on your controller, to subscribe to an event and then to kick off the event. So, in your view you might do:

```
didInsertElement: function () {
    this.get('controller').on('loginDidFail', this, this.loginFail);
}
```

And then in your controller call `this.trigger('loginDidFail')` to kick off your `loginFail` view method.

Remember to remove the handler after the view is dismissed... see the answer below.

Comment: Ember amazes me every day!

Comment: Don't forget to remove the listener if the view is going to be destroyed.

Comment: Looks so unobvious and ugly. If you can make this.get('controller') in view, you should have opportunity to call this.get('view') in controller. It makes me sad(

Comment: @RostyslavDiachok Actually `this.get('view')` make no sense, because you don't how many views are backed by particular controller.

Comment: @kmurph79 you don't, this is not pure jQuery `on`, it's Ember thing.

Comment: @RostyslavDiachok This is a fairly typical implementation of the publish-subscribe design pattern. While it might seem non-obvious on its face, it's a time-tested technique for decoupling your objects. Even if you had a reference to the view on the controller, it wouldn't be good practice for the controller to have the responsibility of kicking off what are, essentially, side-effects.

Comment: I want to trigger the event from a controller and to subscribe to this event from a view controlled by a child controller. PeopleController triggers; PeopleIndexView (backed by PeopleIndexController) subscribes. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Ok, I had this all upside down face. I couldn't find a way to subscribe to a parent controllers events but managed to trigger events on the child controller like this : (from PeopleController) this.controllers.peopleIndex.trigger(...). Note that you need to tell your parent controller that it needs the child controller (needs: ['peopleIndex'])

Answer (score 19):

Just wanted to answer on this question to address the issue with properly removing the listener if the view is cleared (when the route changes). It's also not necessary to use a jquery proxy, since the on/off methods support a target, which is good because unsubscribing  a proxy is definitely more complicated. Revising what Christopher provided:

```
didInsertElement: function()
{
  this.get('controller').on('loginDidFail', this, this.loginFail);
},

willClearRender: function()
{
  this.get('controller').off('loginDidFail', this, this.loginFail);
}
```

Without removing the subscription any subsequent visits to the login route (without reloading the page) will add additional listeners; i.e. memory leaks, errors, and unexpected behavior.

Comment: this is working for fine for me. properly removing listeners.

Comment: Good call on on/off taking a target. No idea why I went with proxy, except maybe it was a personal preference at the time?

Comment: Are there cases where this won't work? I tried removing my listeners like this in both `willClearRender` and `willDestroyElement`, and in both cases I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'off' of undefined`, which means the controller was no longer accessible. I will also note that the view is a sub view, not the parent view that the controller is tied to, if that makes any difference.

Comment: @BillDami Yes there are situations where the off isn't necessary, but you should post a question with a code example, preferably including a JSBin (or another online debugging/code example tool) to demonstrate the issue. You can post a link to the question in this comment thread, so others and I can follow. :)

Comment: @AaronStorck nevermind, the root cause was a bug with an animation extension I use (https://github.com/gigafied/ember-animate). Thanks for following up though!