# How to wait for a promise to be fulfilled before continuing

Tags: ember.js

How can I wait until a Promise is resolved before executing the next line of code?

e.g.

```
var option = null;
if(mustHaveOption){
   option = store.find("option", 1).then(function(option){ return option })
}
//wait until promise is resolved before returning this value
return option;
```

Comment: great question. Trying to work this out. Pretty annoying. Seems promises are great for 'views' but pretty crappy for OO programming. You find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ES6, you can now use the `async/await` syntax. It makes the code much more readable:

```
async getSomeOption() {
  var option = null;
  if (mustHaveOption) {
    option = await store.find("option", 1)
  }
}
return option;
```

*PS: this code could be simplified, but I'd rather keep it close from the example given above.*

Answer (score 7):

rallrall provided the correct answer in his comment: you can't

The solution for me was to redesign my code to return promises and then the receiving function must evaluate the result something along the lines of:

```
function a(){
  var option = null;
    return  mustHaveOption ? store.find("option", 1) : false;
  }    
}

function b(){
   res = a();
   if (!res){
       res.then(function(option){
          // see option here
       });
   }
}
```

Another key solution for me was to use a [hash of promises](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.RSVP.html#method_all).  One creates an array of all the promises that must be resolve before executing the next code:

```
Em.RSVP.Promise.all(arrayOfPromises).then(function(results){
   //code that must be executed only after all of the promises in arrayOfPromises is resolved
});
```

It tooks me a while to wrap my head around this async way of programming - but once I did things work quite nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You can start to show a loading gif, then you can subscribe to the `didLoad` event for the record, inside which you can continue your actual processing..

```
    record = App.User.find(1);

    //show gif..

    record.on("didLoad", function() {
        console.log("ren loaded!");
    });

    //end gif; continue processing..
```

Comment: Unfortunately you've assumed that I'm working in some view which I am not.

Comment: If you are working in the controller, you can send a custom event that  the view can handle and implement the above said functionality. see `Ember.Evented` for the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991871/ember-js-how-to-trigger-view-method-from-controller

Comment: My question remains how can I pause my code until the promise is resolved.

Comment: Also note that App.User.find(1); is deprecated in favour of store.find("option", 1)

Comment: Due to the asynchronous nature of what you are doing, you can't. You have to do your stuff in the callback from find, or trigger some event from here and handle it somewhere else. What are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks rallrall if you provide that as the answer I'll accept it.