# Create a controller event listened to by a component

Tags: ember.js

I'm playing with ideas for making a drag and drop interface. I have multiple components that can be dragged into position over a grid. I will have a button that will allow the user to select different arrangements.

I want a function on the component that sets its position (quite simply with left and top). I want to be able to call this function when the component is inserted, and when a different arrangement is selected.

What I want to do is create an event in the route's controller. I then want each component to be able to listen for the event, and react as necessary. I'm afraid I don't understand enough to make this work. I've read the [API](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Evented.html), and a couple of questions on here ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618604/how-to-call-method-of-a-component-from-a-controller), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991871/ember-js-how-to-trigger-view-method-from-controller)), but no luck.

Here's what I have...

The route's controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';    
export default Ember.Controller.extend(Ember.Evented, {
    actions: {

        callPosition: function(){
            this.trigger('position');
            console.log('Trigger set...');
        },
})
```

And the component:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend(Ember.Evented, {

    didInsertElement : function(){
        this.get('controller').on('position', this, this.position);
    },

    position: function(){
        console.log('event heard by the component');
    },
```

A few things I don't understand:

1. Have I added the Ember.Evented mixin correctly?
2. I've added the listener in the didInsetElement event as per the example. Is this the correct way to ensure the component will listen for the event throughout its lifetime?
3. What's the scope of the event? Can it only be listened for so long at we 'get' the controller that set it?

Your advice is a great help to this budding amateur!

Comment: Have you read that blog bost https://emberway.io/ember-js-and-html5-drag-and-drop-fa5dfe478a9a#.tgfpo6kxu ? Some basic DnD in action here...

Comment: Yeah thanks, that was my starting point. A nice explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *not* try to fire an event on components from the controller! What you *should* do is to pass the variables (`left`, `top`) and then register an observer on them on the component

```
sizeChanged: Ember.on('didInsertElement', Ember.observer('top', 'left' function () {
    // arrange it
}))
```

Now you pass down these attributes when you call the component:

```
{{my-component top=myCoolDnDElement.top left=myCoolDnDElement.left}}
```

And the `sizeChanged` will automatically be called whenever the `top` or `left` attribute changes as well as on `didInsertElement`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991871/ember-js-how-to-trigger-view-method-from-controller) is *not* about components, but about controller/view pairs which are *not longer part of ember*.

Back then every controller had an associated view, which often lead to confusion when to place things on the controller and when on the view.
Back then the separation was between controllers and views, where controllers managed global and local state and views basically managed the rendering.

With the introduction of components this has changed. Components handle local state as well as the rendering for that. Basically every component is a view. But its not anymore magically coupled to a controller, but explicit called from the template. For global state services were introduced.

Today you should follow the DDAU (Data Down Actions Up) principle and pass all actions and attributes explicit to the components in the template.

Components call actions on the parent component and pass updatable attributes and callable actions to child components. Thats how you should handle it.

Comment: Thanks for your in depth answer. This makes a lot of sense.